# The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all() with if elif statement in python

Tags: python

I am facing issue in if else condition. In below code it check only first if condition remaining it skips. But as per my given scenario it should run 2nd elif condition. Not sure why it is not checking 2nd elif statement.
In exception it throws """The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."""

```
def aggregated_cnt_check():
    try:
        #print(not df_src2.empty)

        if pd.isnull(df_src2) or pd.isnull(df_tgt2):
            df_agg_diff = pd.DataFrame()
            return df_agg_diff

        elif not df_src2.empty and not df_tgt2.empty:
            df_agg_merge = df_src2.merge(df_tgt2,
                          indicator=True,
                          how='outer')

            df_agg_merge['src_agg_cnt'] = df_agg_merge['src_agg_cnt'].fillna(0)
            df_agg_merge['tgt_agg_cnt'] = df_agg_merge['tgt_agg_cnt'].fillna(0)

            df_agg_merge['cnt_diff'] = df_agg_merge['src_agg_cnt'].sub(df_agg_merge['tgt_agg_cnt'])
            df_agg_diff = df_agg_merge.loc[lambda x: x['cnt_diff'] != 0].head(100)

            return df_agg_diff

    except Exception as e:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
        loging(datetime.datetime.now(), 'agg', sys.exc_info()[1])
        return np.nan
```

Please guide me what i am missing in above code.

Comment: A dataframe is not a single value, it is many values.  So you have to define to Python how you want those many values to combine to a single True/False.

Comment: dataframe contain one value or null/nan/empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
        if len(df_src2)==0 or len(df_tgt2)==0:
            df_agg_diff = pd.DataFrame()
            return df_agg_diff

        elif len(df_src2)>0 and len(df_tgt2)>0:
            df_agg_merge = df_src2.merge(df_tgt2,
                          indicator=True,
                          how='outer')
```

Sometimes its easier to count the rows of the dataframe as a sanity-check, unless you need to see if values in the dataframe are null obviously. Also you technically don't need the elif condition since the if condition returns. If the condition is met it won't evaluate that elif anyway so there's no need for it here.

```
        if len(df_src2)==0 or len(df_tgt2)==0:
            df_agg_diff = pd.DataFrame()
            return df_agg_diff

        df_agg_merge = df_src2.merge(df_tgt2,
                     indicator=True,
                     how='outer')
```

Comment: i did few changes as per my requirement and its working .Thankyou for your help.